# Plotly scatter with many datapoints yield blurry svg

Tags: python, svg, plotly, scatter-plot

When I export a scatterplot with 10000 datapoints to svg with `fig.write_image("filename.svg")` as [recommended by plotly](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/), I get a blurry svg. Downsampling the data to 1000 datapoints does yield a nice vector image that remains sharp. The limit between sharp and pixelated images lies somewhere between 1000 and 1500 scatterpoints since downsampling to 1500 yields a pixelated image again.

How can I avoid this since I'd like to export figures with more than 1000 datapoints.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 2), columns=list('XY'))
fig =px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Y')
fig.write_image("images/fig1.svg")
```

10000 points

[image: screenshot of sharp svg with 10000 datapoints]

1500 points

[image: screenshot of sharp svg with 1000 datapoints]

1000 points

[image: screenshot of sharp svg with 1000 datapoints]

(I had to make screenshots since stackoverflow does not allow .svg images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer lies [here in the plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter) for `px.scatter`...

> render_mode (str) – One of 'auto', 'svg' or 'webgl', default 'auto'
> Controls the browser API used to draw marks. 'svg’ is appropriate for
> figures of less than 1000 data points, and will allow for
> fully-vectorized output. **'webgl' is likely necessary for acceptable
> performance above 1000 points but rasterizes part of the output**.
> 'auto' uses heuristics to choose the mode.

If you add `render_mode = 'svg'` you should see this pixilation go away.

```py
fig =px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Y', render_mode = 'svg')
```

Comment: This does work indeed, thanks. However, I don't see why it works. According to the documentation, 'svg' is for less than 1000 data points and 'webgl' works for more than 1000. Here there are obviously more than 1000 and 'svg' gives a good result and 'webgl' doesn't.

Comment: webgl is for speed (not appearance)

Answer (score 0):

It looks just fine on my desktop with 10000 points:
[image: 10000 points]
Is it possible that you have a graphic card issue?

Comment: Yours are pixelated too. The export engine converted the dot to raster image. OP is looking for a complete svg output.

Comment: I'm making these figures in a notebook that runs on some server, something like Google Colab, so I can't really tell. I tried running it on a local installation and there it also gives a pixelated result.